# Sending comma seperated string in json request to rest client web service

Tags: json, rest-client, postman

I am using restclient or postman for my web service 
Here in I have to send request json :

```
{"wallpost_id":3338,"share_text_msg":"job fair in usa","logged_in_user_id":37,"receiver_id":19,12}
```

- where i want to send comma separated values, but rest client does not
  allow me to use the above format
- Therefore I am using Postman to    solve the purpose and it is
  working fine in postman. But my team at    *android end* want to use
  it **x-www-form-urlencoded** tab of postman, but there the problem
  arises. Please suggest that how can i    send such format in rest
  client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`19,12` is not a valid number.  If you quote that as a string (e.g. `"19,12"`) does it work?